# How to count frequency of a value in a column of a data frame based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with different traffic signs in different neighborhoods (both are columns). I want to count the quantity of each sign type in each neighborhood.

i could create a query for each neighborhood and the count the value of each sign type like that but there are too many neighborhoods for that to be practical.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the neighbourhood and sign type and do a `size` to have the count of each sign type in each neighbourhood.

Sample code

```
df.groupby(["neighbourhood", "sign_type"]).size()
```